# _Click on TabHost view is not working

Tags: basic4android

On a TabHost view I found there are 3 events. Click, LongClick and TabChanged. I found that only TabChanged works and I would like to use Click since the user may tap a tab and go back to the home screen and may want to tap the same tab again.

Here is the Sub Routine I used with TabChanged, but I would like to use Click instead. Maybe I need to change something in my code other than just changing the _TabChanged to _Click. If so, could you let me know what to change?

```
Sub tbhPagesEventHandler_TabChanged

    ToastMessageShow(tbhPages.CurrentTab,False)

    ' These will make the code easier to read.
    '-----------------------------------------
    Dim intVisitsTab As Int : intVisitsTab = 0
    Dim intMaintenanceTab As Int : intMaintenanceTab = 1

    ' Start the activity the user wants.
    '-----------------------------------
    Select tbhPages.CurrentTab

        Case intVisitsTab
            StartActivity("Visits")

        Case intMaintenanceTab
            StartActivity("Maintenance")
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I found out from Erel that you can't have the same TabHost name in 2 different activities so I renamed one of the TabHosts in the other Activity and all worked well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you found a solution, based on your comment, but thought I'd post this for future readers in case it was useful.

The 'TabHost.Click' event fires when the **content** of the TabHost tab is clicked, not the tab itself.

If you use the following for your code, you can see the difference (this uses `tbPages` as the `TabHost` variable):

```
' Displays the 0-based index of the tab being activated
Sub tbPages_TabChanged
 Msgbox("Current tab is " & tbPages.CurrentTab, "") 
End Sub

' Fires when you click inside the content of the tab page,
' not on the tab itself.
Sub tbPages_Click
  Msgbox("Current tab is " & tbPages.CurrentTab, "")        
End Sub
```

This means you can use the `CurrentTab` property to determine which page the user has selected, and react accordingly:

```
Sub tbPages_TabChanged
  Dim TabIdx as Int
  TabIdx = tbPages.CurrentTab    ' Get the tab just activated
  Select TabIdx
    Case 0
      ' First tab is now active
    Case 1
      ' Second tab active
    Case 2
      ' Third tab active
    Case Else
      MsgBox("Something is badly wrong! We have only three tabs", "HEY")
  End Select
End Sub
```